# pd.merge returning Key Error when sending dataframe into a function

Tags: python, pandas, merge, apply

EMAP is a dataframe and I am using "apply" function to perform some action on every row of EMAP dataframe.

The function "Merge" returns "Key Error" on the columns of "row" argument.

But, when I am using the original dataframe (commented in the code) inside the function for Merge, I receive no error.

```
def merge(row):
    a = row[col_select_Event]
    #a = EMAP[col_select_Event][1:2]
    filtered_RCA = pd.merge(RCA,a, on = col_select_Event, how = 'inner')
    return a

j = EMAP.apply(merge, axis = 1)
```

EMAP data frame is like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | abc |
| Orange | 2 | abc |
| Starwberry | 3 | abc |

RCA data frame is like this

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 |
| Orange | 2 |

col_select_Event = ['A','B']

How do I resolve the error?

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow your question here. We don't know what `col_select_Event`, `row`, `RCA` are, so it's hard to know where things went wrong without guessing. If you can make a minimally reproducible example, something we can copy/paste and run ourselves which exhibits the problem, possibly with a small subset of your data that you create manually, it would probably be easy to see the problem. Creating a minimally reproducible example is often enough for you to see the answer yourself too, it's a great debugging tool.

Comment: can you include a sample of your `EMAP` dataframe? otherwise it will be difficult to help you debug. you can paste the output of `EMAP.head().to_dict()` into your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I came across this in the review queue to reopen.  You could improve this question even more by including the exception text (stack trace).  I can guess the issue, but the stack trace would make it answerable and useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Apply function always each row of a dataframe as Pandas Series.

So, "Row" argument is of Pandas Series datatype.

```
EMAP[col_select_Event][1:2] ------> This is of type DataFrame and hence it works
```

whereas

```
row[col_select_Event] ---------> This is Pandas Series
```

You cannot merge Pandas series to a Pandas Dataframe. This is because when using the apply function, columns of dataframe is converted to index of pandas series.

To enable usage of merge function, you must convert pandas series to pandas dataframe

```
row[col_select_Event].to_frame().T
```

The above code should work.